# Javascript Regex - How to split string to an array based on regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string:

```
"<b>Dispatcher Number1 $CREATED_NEW_INCIDENT$ </b> $BASED_ON$ 1 $EVENTS$"
```

I would like to create an array which includes only the words that start and end in $.
For this example the result that I am looking for is :

```
["$CREATED_NEW_INCIDENT$","$BASED_ON$", "$EVENTS$"]
```

I know that I can do it with regex, but I haven't succeeded yet. 
Moreover, when I find the right regex what do I have to do? split it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to split them. Just match using the regex

```
/\$[^$]+\$/g
```

Like this

```
var str = "<b>Dispatcher Number1 $CREATED_NEW_INCIDENT$ </b> $BASED_ON$ 1 $EVENTS$";
var arr = str.match(/\$[^$]+\$/g);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just start the matching with `$`, till you find a `$`.

```
var regEx = /\$.*?\$/g;
console.log(data.match(regEx));
# [ '$CREATED_NEW_INCIDENT$', '$BASED_ON$', '$EVENTS$' ]
```

Here

- `.` means match any character.
- `.*` means match any character, for zero or more times
- `.*?` means match any character, zero or more times, but match only as minimum as possible.

If we don't use `?` in `.*?`, it will match from the first `$` symbol to the last `$` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var s = "<b>Dispatcher Number1 $CREATED_NEW_INCIDENT$ </b> $BASED_ON$ 1 $EVENTS$";
var m = s.match(/(\$[^$]*\$)/g);
//=> ["$CREATED_NEW_INCIDENT$", "$BASED_ON$", "$EVENTS$"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
"<b>Dispatcher Number1 $CREATED_NEW_INCIDENT$ </b> $BASED_ON$ 1 $EVENTS$".match(/\$[\w]+\$/g)
```